# RubyMine doesnt understand new created .html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

My RubyMine is not recognizing and highliting syntax for new created .html.erb files, it's working however for the files generated before with rails g controller ... ... ...

The thing is that new created .html.erb file is working on localhost, RubyMine is just not highliting the syntax.

Please, see attached picture showing the difference between new created and old .html.erb file:

[image]

[Screenshot of RubyMine workplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MIHA.png)

Comment: Sanity check: try changing the file name to sth else like `contact2.html.erb`

Comment: Thank you, this has helped.

Comment: That means you have registered pattern for that filename. Go to settings/editor/file types, select Text files and check if there is any pattern registered like `contact.html.erb` or similar.

Comment: Excelent, exactly as you said. I removed that pattern and now I can name that file even contact.html.erb and it's working as it supposed to.

But for some reason, it's still red in navigation (as it is in the picture). Do you have an idea what might be the cause? It probably doesn't effect functionality, just don't why is that.

Comment: RubyMine is git-aware. It will automatically highlight files which git does not know about (red), files which has been modified since last commit (blue) and files which has been modified and staged for the commit (green). Actual colors depends on selected theme.